# wrong response status in rspec + devise + factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, factory-bot

so i've been trying to make a basic response test - with 200 and 403. I'm not sure i need to add anything else ..

**accounts_spec.rb**

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::AccountsController, :type => :controller do
  describe "GET index no account" do
    it "has a 403 status code" do
      get :index
      expect(response.status).to eq(403)
    end
  end
  describe "GET index with account" do
    login_user
    it "has a 200 status code" do
      get :index
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
end
```

**Accounts Controller #index**

```
def index
    #show user details
    raise if not current_user
    render json: { :user => current_user.as_json(:except=>[:created_at, :updated_at, :authorization_token, :provider, :uid, :id])}
    rescue
    render nothing: true, status: 403   
end
```

I keep getting

```
1)Api::V1::AccountsController GET index with account has a 200 status code
expected: 200
got: 403
```

Any thoughts on where i'm doing it wrong ?

**UPDATE**

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      sign_in :user, user
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Try to wrap raise with begin block. so begin ...raise... render json: { :user ... rescue  render nothing: true, status: 403  end

Comment: this wrapping doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

Much cleaner implementation

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request?

  def index
    render json: { user: current_user...
  end

protected
  def json_request?
    request.format.json?
  end

  def authenticate
    head :unauthorized unless current_user
  end
end
```

I also recommend in using ActiveModel Serializer https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers. This will separate logic of render json and oy will have a separate class under serializer that defines the json output. So your render method will look like this:

```
render json: current_user, status: :ok
```

app/serializers/user.rb

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attribute :id, :email #list your attributes for json output
end
```

If you want to test json response in your rspec what I find best is testing against json schema like this library https://github.com/sharethrough/json-schema-rspec.

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you for the refactoring, i had no idea writing it like this was possible ... but this doesn't answer what i've asked for. The error is still there

Comment: Did you included devise helpers in your rspec? RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end

Comment: Please write login_user that you use in your test. The only this is that the session is not set from rspec. With factory girl it is like user = FactoryGirl.create(:user) ....user.confirm!....sign_in user

Comment: updated. although i don't know where the user.confirm! should be

Comment: after you create user if you use confirmable module before sign_in :user, user, so create user, confirm sign. Another way is that you set confirmed_at inside your Factory Girl

Comment: i don't know what confirmable module is, but if i set :confirmable in devise then i get a 'undefined local variable confirmed_at error"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114532/discussion-between-mirza-memic-and-alex-lug).